# The right way to design a job model

Tags: python, django, model

I have a silly `Job` model in my app:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    # working info
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    inaugural_date = models.DateField('inaugural date', blank=True)
    resignation_date = models.DateField('resignation date', blank=True)
```

the above model is exactly what I have in my app and this model is used to let user get their college, nothing more.

It works, but I think there must be a better way to design this model, because suppose I want get all the users within the same company and same department in same period of time, its not that easy.

Please help me to reconstruct this model, any suggestion will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
User.objects.filter(
    job_set__company__iexact="wwwww", 
    job_set__department__iexact="xxxxx",
    job_set__inaugural_date__gt=yyyy, 
    job_set__resignation_date__lt=zzzz
)
```

It doesn't seem that complex to me, such query wouldn't be easy if you think in SQL terms, at least for me :)

Comment: so you think my model is fine? I think I should redesign the model

Comment: @chenliang depends on what you're going to use it for. Without any more details, maybe company and department should be their own models instead of charfields, and a textfield for a description of the job?, salary? I really can't know... it depends. But for that query is enough in my opinion.

Comment: @chenliang your model is fine, given this exact model and little info on your domain overall your model does its job 100% perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how much you predict on growing and what backend you use. For relation db (mysql/postgres etc) I would create a separate model for departments and companies and also create join tables for them in order to make my job easier later on.

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Your model looks fine.

Even though Django model is not [Anemic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) , I usually look it as pure data structure without too much logic. So I think

> get all the users within the same company and same department in same period of time

is a logic which should not be a concern of your model, which also means, it should not influence your model design too much IMHO.

Model should be kept simple and thin, so that it can be adopted and adapted in/to different kinds of logic. If you try to make you model structure suitable to a specific logic, you will easily find yourself entangled with inflating models.

BTW, for complex query, you can fallback to [Raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: I thought if I design my model better,my code in query logic should be really simple,and scales well,even though I know I really should not worry much about scale,especially at the very beginning， but for the sake of learning,I really like to build my model better! Two chinese talks in english，interesting!

Comment: If you know what the **better** is, follow it. If you don't know or not very clear on it, may my answer be one of the factors of consideration ;-).